# Why is photon quantized in vacuum?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency, discrete

Apparition of quantized energy levels in quantum physics is usually explained in  analogy with sound waves in a box (like in music instruments): the wave has to satisfy the boundary conditions and only specific modes can exist in the cavity, hence specific energies and frequencies. That explains well the quantized energies of electrons in infinite wells or in atoms for exampples. 
But photons in vacuum are also quantized, with energies proportional to n*h*nu. Does anyone have any intuitive explanation for that, not implying computations like field quantization?

Comment: This question is largely answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/298631/are-photon-energies-universally-quantized). Photon energy is not quantized, their energy is h\*nu, not n\*h\*nu. Photons emitted by electrons in bound states will have energy defined by the energy levels of the electron, but this does not limit them to a particular energy level like it does for an electron.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are photon energies universally quantized?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298631/)